# What would I lose from switching from iPhone 4+ e-reader to dumbphone+iPad

Tags: ipad, iphone

I'm currently using an iPhone 4 and a cheap e-reader that was given to me as a gift. I don't think I can afford both an iPhone and an iPad, so I was considering switching to a dumbphone (non-smartphone) and an iPad. What features would i lose, or miss, from making this switch - specifically in the iphone-ipad part?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me that you would spend less money overall if you just kept the iPhone and got a wifi-only iPad rather than switching phones and plans (not including that nasty early termination fee on the iPhone contracts). That is what I have now and I really like it.

But, to answer your question specifically, even taking into consideration the iOS 4 release for iPad later this year, you will be missing, at minimum, all of the camera-related functionality of the iPhone, but then there is visual voicemail and easy (and cheap) email. That's a lot to give up all things considered.

Answer (score 5):

The internet, and a pretty great camera, in your pocket.

Comment: @Philip: Aw, cheers Philip. I do get surprised at how often I hear people talk about getting an iPad *instead of* an iPhone. They run the same OS, but they’re very different devices.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good answers already given, there's also:

- [FaceTime](http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/facetime.html)
- [Video](http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/hd-video-recording.html)
- Synchronization (you'd have to always manually update your phone contacts)

Also worth mentioning: if you buy a 3G iPad there's no monthly charge unless/until you sign a carrier agreement. IMO, you're always better off buying one with 3G if there's a >0% chance you'll need it someday. Yes, it's more money initially, but it's a one-time charge.

Answer (score 1):

Split the question into two separate items and make a decision about them:

- (Why) Do you want an iPad?
- (Why) Do you want to replace your iPhone with a simpler one?

For instance, even if you get an iPad, it would still be convenient to keep the iPhone. Also, if you jailbreak your iPhone, you could broadcast your iPhone's Internet access as a local WIFI hotspot that your iPad could connect to = the cheaper WIFI-only iPad would suffice, rather than getting the 3G version when you're *already* paying for a 3G data plan for your iPhone.